# Python ML Model with ExtraTreesClassifier

Tags: python

Does anybody can see what I'm doing wrong?

**Input:**

```
from sklearn.ensemble import ExtraTreesClassifier
modelo = ExtraTreesClassifier()
modelo.fit(x_treino,y_treino)

resultado = modelo.score(x_teste, y_teste)
print("Acurácia", resultado)
```

**Output: i'm having this errors**

```
D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_X_y(X, y, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, multi_output, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, y_numeric, estimator)
    869         raise ValueError("y cannot be None")
    870 
--> 871     X = check_array(X, accept_sparse=accept_sparse,
    872                     accept_large_sparse=accept_large_sparse,
    873                     dtype=dtype, order=order, copy=copy,

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     61             extra_args = len(args) - len(all_args)
     62             if extra_args <= 0:
---> 63                 return f(*args, **kwargs)
     64 
     65             # extra_args > 0

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, estimator)
    671                     array = array.astype(dtype, casting="unsafe", copy=False)
    672                 else:
--> 673                     array = np.asarray(array, order=order, dtype=dtype)
    674             except ComplexWarning as complex_warning:
    675                 raise ValueError("Complex data not supported\n"

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
    100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, like=like)
    101 
--> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    103 
    104 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __array__(self, dtype)
   1991 
   1992     def __array__(self, dtype: NpDtype | None = None) -> np.ndarray:
-> 1993         return np.asarray(self._values, dtype=dtype)
   1994 
   1995     def __array_wrap__(

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py in asarray(a, dtype, order, like)
    100         return _asarray_with_like(a, dtype=dtype, order=order, like=like)
    101 
--> 102     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
    103 
    104 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'M'
```

MACHINE LEARNING MODEL USIN PYTHON WITH THE FUNCTION ExtraTreesClassifier now I don't have anything else to share but sof is making me write more to post this so ignore this texte here pls.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us what is the type of the data (x_treino,y_treino)? Type as in `float`, `str` ect.

Comment: My data is: Age: 23, Sex: M or F, Blood Pressure: High or Low, Cholesterol: High or Normal, Na to K: numbers like 25.355, Drug: DrugX (example based on the first line of the table)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so from your comment I can see that the data has only two numerical variables (Age, Na to K), while the rest are categorical (Sex, Blood Pressure, Cholesterol, Drug). `ExtraTreesClassifier` can only work with numerical variables hence the `ValueError`. To combat this you should first preprocess the data so that they are transformed to numeric and especially `float` so that they are able to be handled by the classifier.

Some preprocessing algorithms for your case would be `LabelEncoder`, `OrdinalEncoder` or maybe `OneHotEncoder`, depending on the data and your methods.

Here's the full documentation page (you're looking for categorical to numeric transformations):
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.preprocessing

If your question was answered please consider marking it as solved.